# Applying more than one texture to different images in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to paint a doll using html, I have already set the different parts of the doll in different image files and I am now trying to load different textures to each of those parts, using canvas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Canvas with textures</title> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var c = document.getElementById("previewCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");       

        var hair = new Image();
        hair.src = "images/hair_1.png";
        //ctx.drawImage(hair, 0, 0, 300, 300);

        var head = new Image();
        head.src = "images/head_base.png";

        hair.onload = function () {

        };

        var textureSkin = new Image();
        textureSkin.src = "img/textures/texture_skin.png";


        var textureImg = new Image();
        textureImg.src = "img/textures/texture_black.png";


        textureImg.onload = function () 
        {
            var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(textureSkin, 'repeat');

            ctx.drawImage(head, 0, 0, 300, 300);

            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

            ctx.drawImage(hair, 0, 0, 300, 300);            
        }
        });

</script>


    <body>
            <canvas id= "previewCanvas" height="600" width="400"/>  
    </body>
</html>
```

The previous code outputs me this combined image:

[image]

If I try to load a new texture after painting the hair (as I want the hair to have a custom texture too), doing something like this:

```
    textureSkin.onload = function () 
    {
        var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(textureSkin, 'repeat');        
        ctx.drawImage(head, 0, 0, 300, 300);

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
        ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    }       

    var textureImg = new Image();
    textureImg.src = "img/textures/texture_black.png";


    textureImg.onload = function () 
    {

        var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(textureImg, 'repeat'); 
        ctx.drawImage(hair, 0, 0, 300, 300);            
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
        ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);


    }
    });
```

both images get combined and the last texture (textureImg) gets applied :

[image]

What is the correct way to load different textures, for different images in the same canvas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Both images looks combined, because you are using "repeat". Try using "no-repeat". Also, give exact coordinates for the texture.

See below code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Canvas with textures</title> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx;
var textureSkin;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

        var c = document.getElementById("previewCanvas");
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");       

        var hair = new Image();
        hair.src = "http://www.jawad.pk/images/mus.png";
        //ctx.drawImage(hair, 0, 0, 300, 300);

        var head = new Image();
        head.src = "http://www.jawad.pk/images/head.png";



        textureSkin = new Image();
        textureSkin.src = "http://www.jawad.pk/images/mus2.png";


        textureSkin.onload = function () 
        {
            var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(textureSkin, 'no-repeat');

            ctx.drawImage(head, 0, 0, 300, 300);

            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;            
   
   ctx.drawImage(hair, 100, 200, 100, 38);
   
     
        }
  
  
  
        });
  
  function applyTexture()
  {
   ctx.drawImage(textureSkin, 100, 200, 100, 38); 
  }

</script>




    <body>
  <a style="border:1px solid red; color:red; cursor:pointer" onclick="applyTexture()">apply texture</a>
            <canvas id= "previewCanvas" height="300" width="400"/>  
  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, how would you apply a texture to the face image in your example, after setting the texture for the mustache?

Answer (score 0):

You could use another canvas as a staging area in which to apply different textures to each of the parts.  Depending on your target browser(s), you may be able to use [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas).